# Unable to Install: my .msi file

Tags: asp.net, winforms

I have develop a system in `asp.net` using win form and made its `.msi` file. I have installed it on my system it works perfect but when i try to install it on clients system it gives me following error.

The framework i'm using is `4.5 Visual studio 2013`

[This is the error i'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRwPa.jpg).
Need serious suggestion to resolve this error.

Comment: Well, did you deploy that assembly? Also: you developed an ASP.NET application, why do you have a dependency to the WinForms report viewer client?!

Comment: yes i deploy it with assembly. I'm not sure why it show me dependency on WinForm when deploy on client projects.

Comment: Exception details may help you to see where it's used

Comment: i think you need `SQL Server CLR Types` and `Microsoft Visual Studio Report Viewer`. see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx

Comment: @NagibMahfuz Thanks you ans sort my problem to some what.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all .My problem sorted out using visual studio installer i add primary out and localize resources of the product in exe. Bingo the problem go on.